# Custom Control datasource use in Xpage

Tags: xpages

How can I use a custom control datasource (named doc) in XPage Application layout?
I need to control read mode and edit mode through the basic node of the place bar.
When I put the code `doc.isEditable()` in the rendered property, the following error is display in the browser:

```
Error while executing JavaScript computed expression
Script interpreter error, line=1, col=6: [ReferenceError] 'doc' not found
```

JavaScript code

```
doc.isEditable();
```

I am new to Xpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post some code? not entirely sure what you mean.

Generally the best place to define a data source is at the top of the XPage so that every control beneath it has access to it. If your defining a data source after your trying to query it you would get an error like this

Comment: Then how I will bind the fields in custom control if there is no datasource? I add the datasource in XPage, the error is not generated now. thanks for your tip.

Comment: if the data source is defined on the XPage and the custom control is inside the same XPage as well then you can bind the document fields to controls inside the custom control just as you would in any other situation, nothing changes when its a custom control. Custom controls just help you to abstract out groups of controls / code that will be used in multiple places

Comment: one more question, here in place bar when we add basic node how we add script of save document and send email?

Comment: the basic nodes only allow to execute client side script, while there may be some ways around this its quite advanced if your new to XPages. they are generally only for navigation links and the like. I would avoid using this as it would be MUCH easier to add something to one of the layouts facets such as the LeftColumn, RightColumn, MiddleColumn etc. You could make a custom control that you add into every page that could sit on top and that would do the same thing but a lot easier as you would have more control

Comment: Thanks for your advice Simon McLaughlin.

Comment: Is that possible that I use custom control on the basis of scope variable? If yes then how can I do that? My code is [code]<![CDATA[#{javascript:
       if ( viewScope.viewName=="ccViewAll"){
        #]]><xc:ccViewAll></xc:ccViewAll>
       <![CDATA[#{javascript:}
       else{
        #]]><xc:ccViewAll_1></xc:ccViewAll_1>
       <![CDATA[#{javascript:}
      }
     ]]> [/code]. Syntax is ok but, there is something wrong because out is not correct.

Comment: I think your trying to computer which custom control gets shown? you can't do it this way but you can use the "loaded" property on a control / custom control to decide if a control gets loaded or the "rendered" property to say if its gets shown on the page. You should have asked this as a new question on stack overflow as other people may have a similar question and they won't find it here. If I have answered the question above well enough for you, you should mark this as the top answer and ask new questions so other developers can learn from them too.